# Laravel - blade check if object has relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In my controller I'm getting a complex query that filter data depending on input provided by the user:

```
if (conditionB) {
   $query = Model::with('relationA', 'relationB');
} else {
   $query = Model::with('relationA', 'relationC');
}

// checking filters and apply conditions...

$query = $query->get();
```

Now in my blade file I'm looping result and I want to display "eager load" relationship B or C:

```
@if (count($myObject->relationB)) {
    <span>{{ $myObject->relationB->someField }}</span>
@else
    <span>{{ $myObject->relationC->someField }}</span>
@endif
```

It works, but if my `$myObject` has `relationC` and not `relationB`, then 
during the verification of the if condition the relationship is loaded.

How I can avoid loading that relationship??

when I do: `{{ $myObject }}`

It gives me:

```
   // has relationB
   "field1": value1,
   "field2": value2,
    ....
   "fieldx": valuex,
   "relation_b":[  
      { 
         "relationBfield1": relationBvalue1,
         "relationBfield2": relationBvalue2,
      },
      { ... }

   // doesn't have relationB
   "field1": value1,
   "field2": value2,
    ....
   "fieldx": valuex
```

I tried access relation_b (note that json is changing name by replacing `UpperCase` for `_<LowerCase>`) but it returns NULL, but if I access relationB it shows data:

```
myObject->relation_b; // NULL
myObject->relation_b[0]; // NULL
myObject->relationB; // works, but if item has RelationC it will "eager load" relationship B just to check that if condition
```

I was trying different options, and I don't see where I make mistake, I also tried to create a `public function` in my model:

```
{{ $myObject->checkRelation() }}

public function checkRelation()
{
    if (count($this->relationB) > 0) {
        // code...
```

But I always end up with the same problem, when object item doesn't have relationB it will load it to check that if condition.

How can I avoid it? Or there is another way to check with relation has my object item without executing an additional query?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a relationship has been loaded you can use the `relationLoaded()` method on the model:

```
@if ($myObject->relationLoaded('relationB')) {
    <span>{{ $myObject->relationB->someField }}</span>
@else
    <span>{{ $myObject->relationC->someField }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for! Working as expected, now I don't have additional queries.